# fatal error function must be a string

Tags: php, mysql, database, image-upload

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        $con_db=mysql_select_db('test');

        if(!$con_db)echo"Error Connecting";

        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['type']);

        echo $imageName;


        if(substr($imageType,0,5)=="image"){
            mysql_query('insert into image values("","$imageData","imageName")');
        }
        else echo "Select Image to Post";
    }
?>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <td><tr>Upload image</tr><td><input type="file" name="image"></td>
            <td><tr></tr><tr><input type="submit" name="submit"></tr></td>

        </table>
```

I here have created a form and tried to upload the pic it got uploaded when i try to show the uploaded image its showing that there is a fatal error function must be a string

```
<?php
        $my_con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('test');

        $getid = $_GET('id');

        if(isset($getid)){
            $id = $getid;
            $db_query = mysql_query("select * from 'image' where id='$id'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($db_query)){
                $imageData = $row['image'];
            }
            header("content-type: image");
        }
        else{
            echo "Error!";  
        }
    ?>
```

This is another php file to display the image

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices.

Comment: `$_GET['id'];` not `$_GET('id');`

Comment: Thanks hope i will find it helpful! Mr. Alex

Comment: but i'm just using it for a time being to create a website for my college project

Comment: but i get this a lot what is the difference between PDO and MySQLi